Is it possible to have a private ip address in 160.98.X.Y?
When I look for my private IP address, it shows up 160.98.XXX.YYY.
Is it possible because it isn't in a private class IP address (A, B, C)?
en0:
    ether XXX
    inet 160.98.XXX.YYY netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 160.98.XXX.YYY


No. 160.97.0.0 - 160.100.255.255 are public addresses that are already allocated.

Adding to @GregAskew's comment: If you have set an IP inside the shown range; i.e. there would be TWO computers having the same IP (one local and one on the internet); HOW would the tcp/ip stack know which of the PC:s you're asking to communicate with?

@Hannu In fact, I have a public IP address on my computer. So there is only one IP address such as mine on the Internet.

@Hannu: It doesn't sound like that from OP's question – it sounds like those are the same PC.

Right; The presence of "private" fooled me.


Is it possible to have a private ip address in 160.98.X.Y?

In this question you're thinking backwards. When an address is assigned to your Ethernet interface, that does not make it "your private address". It is your address, yes, but there is no requirement for it to be a private address specifically.
Indeed "public" (normal) IP addresses are the most standard way to build a network, and the major reason we use private addresses for LANs today is simply that there usually aren't enough public addresses for all devices. But if an organization has enough public addresses, then it is completely valid for it to use public addresses for its network (or at least parts of it).

For us to really indicate whether this address is suitable for the host, we need to know where the host resides and who allocated the address. If it's inside a private network (i.e: behind a NATing router), then this is likely an unsuitable address... but if it's on the public internet, then this could well be fine!
At least some of (all of?) the 160.98.0.0/16 range is allocated to the HEIA / HES-SO Fribourg, and they (Universities) still often use publicly routable addresses across their whole network, with no NAT - you'll probably be allocated a public address by DHCP, even if the firewall prevents direct access from outside.
Note: This is also a good example of why masking an IP address isn't always as effective as you might hope!

Well spotted, I hadn't thought to check before posting, Thanks.
